# how to differentiate user and admin in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing php project. Senario is there is ADMIN and USER as usually.

> 1.ADMIN- can access every thing. Andmin can add owners and employees
>      2.Owner -Can only see its own company employee and can add employees
>      3.Employee Can only see its own information.

How i can apply this security. shall i use session or parameters or what anther things available?

When i display data how i can diffentiate in sql its admin,owner or emplyee.

```
"select Employee_id, firstname,lastname ,Address,Epost from tbl_employee where company_id='$companyid'"
```

if its Admin how i can change companyid  to see all employee e.g

```
select * from tbl_employee
```

Comment: How does your site distinguish the users? Different code for different users is usually done completely in php (apart from stroing rights and users in mysql), e.g. check rights on every page depending on the sessionvariables, and execute different code for different access rights. Usually, frameworks already support such kind of stuff, maybe try one.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should create a specific way for differentiating your user types. Some sort of

1. Admin - (tinyint) 1
2. Owner - (tinyint) 2
3. Employee - (tinyint) 3

Then in your database you should have ( type, access, level ) whatever you call it and in there the type of access given user has: 1 ( for example )

Your SQL will then become:

```
"select Employee_id, firstname,lastname ,Address,Epost, type from tbl_employee where company_id='$companyid'"
```

and the last step is that in every page you will make a check for the type and print the needed information.

If its a basic php project it will be simple if statement. If it is framework then it will be identity interface and so on.

P.S.

If you want the admin to see the employees you will do something like this:

```
SELECT `company_id` FROM `company_table` WHERE `user_id` = '{$user_id}'
```

Then when you have company ID you will do the

```
"select Employee_id, firstname,lastname ,Address,Epost, type from tbl_employee where company_id='$companyid' AND `type` = '3'"
```